# I made butternut squash soup and it asked for garlic but it is overpoweringly garlicky how do I fix that

Tags: soup

I am making a butternut squash soup it asked for garlic shallots maple syrup garlic butter salt pepper and nutmeg. When it was all blended together it was a little bland so I added additional garlic and some time. Now I get an overwhelming aftertaste of garlic. Can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Was the first garlic/shallots cooked with the soup, and second addition of garlic raw?

If so, try cooking it some more. In future, consider "roasting" (which for typical roasted garlic recipes is 99% steaming in foil in the oven with oil - there's a little caramelization, but it's not roasting in the usual sense of the word) the additional garlic before adding it to mellow it out.

Comment: We should also check that it was fresh garlic from a bulb and not some pre-prepared product (which is likely to be cooked, though not necessarily enough).

Answer (score 2):

- Add more of the other ingredients to make a larger volume of soup with proportionally less garlic.
- Add other flavorful ingredients like those already in the soup to help balance the flavour.
- You could try simmering the soup for a while which may mellow out the garlic flavour.
- In future be careful about adding too much of an ingredient as you taste; as you have found it's much easier to add than to take away. It also sounds like it added raw blended garlic rather than cooking it, which explains the intense taste you're getting – garlic's flavour changes significantly as it is cooked.

Answer (score 0):

**Left turn to curry!**

Garlic will be happy to see its friends cumin and ginger show up!  Maybe some toasted nuts.   Cardamom?  Turn your soup into a curry and serve over rice.